# Method for Saving / Loading Game Levels in Python

Tags: python, yaml, pygame, pickle

I'm writing a game using Python and PyGame. (This is perscribed in the assignment, so it's no use suggesting another game dev. library that has built-in level parsing)

I'm at the stage now where the game physics etc. are complete, but I am yet to work out a method for saving and loading levels into the game. Here's what I've thought about it so far:

#### 1. Method Brainstorm

- Have been suggested YAML (Therefore, [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML)) for handling level input / output.

  - This stores as plain text, but in a structured mannar.
  - Easy to edit etc. - one of YAML's major features is that it is easy to be humanly readable.
- Using pickle

  - Which I have used in the past - save a list as individual items with a splitter item to differentiate them.
  - Again, saves as plain text, but using a splitter item (for example, {><} as with the Learner Driver Logbook makes it harder to understand.

#### 2. Data Representation

- Each level needs the follow data to be parsed. The data types are in bold next to it.

  - The starting positions and characteristics of balls and circles **[Two lists]**
  - The limit on circles **[Integer]**
  - Permitted colours **[Definition List Colour:True / Colour:False]**
  - The Obsessive Completion Distinction criteria **[Integer]**
  - Any storyline or tutorial text that must appear in level **[List of strings]**
  - Level name and number **[List of strings]**

All I'm looking for are suggestions of the best method for achieving this.

**TL;DR - Best way to parse game levels from file into Python / PyGame.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need to edit by hand, or read the levels in any other program, just use `pickle`.

Store your level data in a single Python object, and it's (nearly) a one-liner in your code to read and write.

Answer (score 2):

Pickle is made for this sort of thing. You don't need any delimiter to differentiate the items in a list; just pickle the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

How about the simple approach of a .txt file?

For example if it was a 2D game, have id's, so 3=stone, 4=grass, and then just read line by line and transfer to the display.

This is good for level editors, as it is easy for them to save data. This is not a good option though if its important data which needs encrypting.

Answer (score 0):

Doing testing on persistence within your program can be extremely difficult. For instance, can you test that each level will save and load the exact same state? (Or relatively the same state -- some games may have timer states that will not be duplicated exactly.)

My suggestion would be to use a readable text format because that's what I've used in my programs. Why use something that you can't read or compare easily?

Comment: Ok, so this makes sense. There's the trade-off, of course, between 'enabling' cheating and easy development. Would you have any library/module to suggest for the parsing?

Comment: No particular suggestion. You already mentioned PyYAML, and that would be fine. I've had custom text formats because of my requirements, so I've always just parsed it myself (not that hard in Python). IMO, you should focus on making a really good game first, and worry about "cheating" later. If you're really worried, you can always use a readable format during development/debugging and switch to a binary format (that uses the same interface) later, if needed.